# Files hidden on USB hard disk because of virus, how to clean?

Tags: usb, virus

I have 1 GB hard drive with files hidden on it due to a virus. All of its contents were gone after a virus got in when I gave the drive to someone else. After research found that it was a virus may be.

I ran Nortan Anti-Virus and removed a certain virus. Then ran Malwarebytes, now Ad-Aware and AVG 2011 Anti-Virus.

After that, I could see the files on my other computer. But now I have hooked this to my new MacBook Pro—which is running Windows—I can’t see the files. The Anti-Virus finds all the files and Mac OS X wrote a 400 MB directory there which I can see but nothing else.

How to fix this? Which program will fix it?

Comment: If you don't need the data, format the drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This virus has been going around quite a bit recently and I have fixed it at least 10 times myself in the past couple of weeks.

Whilst the removers try to do a good job at removing the rootkit, they do not undo the actual damage caused by it. (Also, I have seen a few varieties that remain and can redirect Google search results, you may want to warn your friend).

I am not sure of a good/quick/easy way from a Mac, but, the easiest thing you can do from a Windows machine is to go to a command prompt (do not think you need elevated, but if you get an error, do it), and type the following:

```
x:
cd\
attrib -h /S
```

Replace x: with the letter assigned to the drive. This will go through all files on the drive and remove the hidden attribute. Unfortunately, if you have manually set it on any, this will be wiped - but not a lot of people do this on their own files.

Hope this helps, if you need any follow up help, especially as this isn't that easy, please write a comment and I (or someone else) will try to help you.

Comment: In my case the folder were made hidden as well as system files so you this command instead attrib -h -s "folder name". /s attribe did not work on mac in root folder.

Answer (score 3):

Try to kill the Autorun file by following these steps:

1. Download the file [AutorunExterminator](http://en.kioskea.net/download/download-11613-autorun-exterminator)

   Extract it --> Double-click on "AutorunExterminator" --> Plug in your external hard drive.

   This will remove the autorun.inf files from your external hard drive.
2. Run the following command. Here I assume your external hard drive is G:

   ```
   attrib -h -r -s /s /d g:\*.*
   ```

   You can copy the above command and then right-click in the Command Prompt to paste it.
   (Or do "Start" --> "Run" and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.)
3. Download [Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware](http://en.kioskea.net/download/download-105-malwarebytes-anti-malware), update it, and perform a full scan.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see files on one computer and not another (new install) you may have turned off displaying hidden files on MBP/Win machine. Check that you have turned on displaying hidden files (Control Panel > Folder Options > View tab > Hidden files and folders - Show...

If this does not resolve the issue - using the computer where you can see files, check file properties and turn off hidden bit.

Comment: I have enabled viwing hidden files. I see other system files but not the files that I want. There is 300+ GB of data.